# file hashing by identifying files by first 4 bytes

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script to search through my current directory to identify jpg by their header then hash those files.  I'm kind of all over the place.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join, normpath, basename
import hashlib

jpgHead = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0'

def get_files():
    current_path = normpath(getcwd())
    return [join(current_path, f) for f in listdir(current_path) if 
isfile(join(current_path, f))] 

def checkJPG():
    checkJPG=checkJPG.read(4)
    if checkJPG==jpgHead
    get_hashes()

def get_hashes():
    files = checkJPG()
    list_of_hashes = []
    for each_file in files:
        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(each_file, "rb") as f: 
        list_of_hashes.append('Filename: {}\tHash: 
        {}\n'.format(basename(each_file), hash_md5.hexdigest()))
        return list_of_hashes

def write_jpgHashes():
    hashes=get_hashes()
    with open('list_of_hashes.txt', 'w') as f:
        for md5_hash in hashes:
        f.write(md5_hash)


if __name__ == '__main__':

write_jpgHashes()
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example such that other can reproduce your problem and ask questions regarding a specific issue; not broad how to program questions giving the full source code.

Comment: There are several problems with this code. There are a couple of blocks that need to be indented, an `if` statement without a colon, `get_files` is defined but never called, `checkJPG` returns `None` but `get_hashes` expects it to return files, also those 2 functions call each other in an infinite recursive loop. Etc.

Comment: Also, `checkJPG=checkJPG.read(4)` is rather strange.And you never actually hash any of the file data.

Answer (score 0):

I modified some of your functions a bit , give it a try

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join, normpath, basename
import hashlib

jpgHead = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0'

def get_files(path = getcwd()):
    current_path = normpath(path)
    return [ join(current_path, f) for f in listdir(current_path) if isfile(join(current_path, f)) ] 

def checkJPG(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f : 
        header = f.read(4)
    return header == jpgHead

def get_hashes():
    list_of_hashes = []
    for each_file in get_files() :
        if checkJPG(each_file) : 
            list_of_hashes.append('Filename: {}\tHash: {}\n'.format(each_file, md5hf(each_file)))
    return list_of_hashes

def md5hf(path): 
    #return hashlib.md5(open(path, "rb").read()).hexdigest()  ## you can use this line for small files ##  
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda : f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

def write_jpgHashes():
    hashes=get_hashes()
    with open('list_of_hashes.txt', 'w') as f:
        for md5_hash in hashes:
            f.write(md5_hash)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_jpgHashes()
```

Notes :

1. Fixed some syntax and indentation errors
2. Turned `checkJPG` to boolean
3. Added the md5 hash of files to `list_of_hashes` in `get_hashes`
4. Added the `md5hf` function , to get the md5 checksum